# Unable to add python to PATH

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to python, but it seems like I should be able to activate the python environment by simply typing `python`. Unfortunately, I keep getting the error "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." I can access python through it's path at `C:\Python27\python`, which works fine, but I can't seem to get the shortcut to work.

Details: I manually installed Python 2.7, and I run Windows 10. I have tried going to the Advanced System Settings to add the PATH manually, but with no result. None of the tutorials or help articles have suggestions for what to do if adding it manually fails. Is there any way I can fix this? It seems like a small thing, but it's really bugging me.

Comment: Sorry if this is insulting, but you did restart the computer, right? Windows can't add to PATH until you do

Comment: can you open a command prompt and execute `echo %PATH%`

Comment: restarting the system should fix the problem, no need to say `python` go to run type `py` enter and it's there!

Comment: Yes, the result I get is: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\jEdit;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;"C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27";C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\Maria\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;'

Comment: And yes, I did try restarting it. With a couple different PATH configurations, as per different tutorials.

Comment: Okay cool! Always better to start with the most obvious thing

Comment: You've got extra double quotation marks in your path.  Remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path configuration is incorrect; your path should look like this:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\‌​WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\S‌​ystem32\Wbem;C:\WIND‌​OWS\System32\Windows‌​PowerShell\v1.0\;C:\‌​Program
>   Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\jEdit;C:\Program
>   Files\Git\cmd;C:\Python27\;C‌​:\Python27\Scripts;C‌​:\Users\Maria\AppDat‌​a\Local\Microsoft\Wi‌​ndowsApps;

After changing the path, make sure you restart the command prompt or any other application that needs to use Python (or you can just restart the computer).

Answer (score 0):

Your path is bugged:

`C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;"C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27";C‌​:\Python27\Scripts`

should not have those random `"` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH variable has double quotes in ("C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27") which you should remove and try python command again on command prompt (cmd).

```
`C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\‌​WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\S‌​ystem32\Wbem;C:\WIND‌​OWS\System32\Windows‌​PowerShell\v1.0\;C:\‌​Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\;C:\Program Files\jEdit;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;"C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27";C‌​:\Python27\Scripts;C‌​:\Users\Maria\AppDat‌​a\Local\Microsoft\Wi‌​ndowsApps;'
```

Remove double quotes from below ...

```
"C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Python27"
```